# How to refresh div in ajax every 10 seconds

Tags: asp.net, ajax

So, how can I refresh one div in updatepanel or somehting, every 10 seconds?

Comment: google http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc295400.aspx

Answer (score 1):

I would do that with plain Javascript. [window.setTimeout](https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/DOM/window.setTimeout) should help. Also very helpful for one div would be the jQuery [load()](http://api.jquery.com/load/) method.